# TRY(hd0,0) NTFS5 error while booting Ubuntu installed as Wubi

Tags: 12.10, boot, wubi

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 using Wubi installer. When I boot Ubuntu from boot menu then it shows the following and it sticks there forever:

> TRY(hd0,0) :NTFS5:

What's the problem and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is posted in [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1838524) take a look at it